# How do you identify the tangent space of the Jacobian variety with differential forms of the first kind?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, abelian-varieties

I know that the Jacobian variety of a Riemann surface $X$ can be defined as $$Jac(X) = (\Omega_{hol}^{1}(X))^{*}/\text{H}_1(X, \mathbb{Z}).$$ My question is how do you canonically identify its tangent space with the space $\Omega_{hol}^1(X)$, because as far as I understand, its tangent space is canonically isomorphic to the dual space $(\Omega_{hol}^1(X))^*$. I've searched for a while and I could only find a proof of this that uses algebraic geometry machinery, is there any way to see this at the level of manifolds?

Comment: What is the precise statement you are looking for? The tangent space of Jacobian is either identified with $\Omega^1_{hol}(X)^*$ or $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ via Hodge-Riemann bilinear pairing. It does not seem to me can be identified with $\Omega^1_{hol}(X)$ naturally.